# Update Table that uses JOIN to find proper record

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to update a record in a table which requires me to user INNER JOIN to find proper record.

```
   SELECT T2.*
   FROM Schema.Table2 T2 INNER JOIN 
     Schema.Table1 T1 ON T2.Key_Column = T1.Key_Column
   WHERE T2.ID = @ID AND T1.Code = '1'
```

Tried

```
UPDATE Schema.Table2 T2
SET T2.col1 = @Var1,
    T2.col2 = @Var2,
    T2.col3 = @Var3
WHERE T2.Key_Column = (SELECT T2.*
                       FROM Schema.Table2 T2 INNER JOIN 
                       Schema.Table1 T1 ON T2.Key_Column = T1.Key_Column
                       WHERE T2.ID = @ID AND T1.Code = '1')
```

Please help!

Comment: looks close already, what goes wrong?

Comment: Thanks guys, they both work (seems like they are same). TIL no need of subquery while updating a table that requires inner join to find the right record. :) Will accept both as answer after 7 minutes. @Jodrell: Modified my query to make it clear where I went wrong. :)

Comment: @user1569220: You cannot accept both. You can only accept one answer.

Comment: Oops, I accepted the first answer. :) Thanks @Jodrell for trying to help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a subselect:

```
UPDATE T2
SET T2.col1 = @Var1,
    T2.col2 = @Var2,
    T2.col3 = @Var3
FROM Schema.Table2 T2 INNER JOIN 
     Schema.Table1 T1 ON T2.Key_Column = T1.Key_Column
WHERE T2.ID = @ID AND T1.Code = '1'
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
UPDATE Schema.Table2
        SET
            col1 = @Var1,
            col2 = @Var2,
            col3 = @Var3
    FROM
            Schema.Table2 T2
        INNER JOIN 
            Schema.Table1 T1 
                ON T2.Key_Column = T1.Key_Column
    WHERE 
            T2.ID = @ID 
        AND 
            T1.Code = '1'
```